# Get Points in CorePlot as I drag

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, graph, core-plot

I would like to do something like this but using core plot:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

@IBAction func pan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
 var coordinate = sender.locationInView(UIView?())
display.text = "\(coordinate)"
}}
```

This gets the coordinates of the point of the screen as I pan around. Would it be possible to do this in a Core Plot graph? (using the plotAreaTouchDown methods if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Get the coordinate in the hosting view (`sender.locationInView(hostingView)`). Convert it to the plot area layer coordinate system using the `CALayer` coordinate conversion methods and then use the plot space to convert it to data coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to get a different point than using the plotPointForEvent in plotAreaWasSelected func though. [see code](http://s1.postimg.org/j8x7vj0jj/Untitled.png)

Comment: the plotPointForEvent one, using the plotAreaWasSelected(with UIEvent) func.

Comment: Show the code you use to convert the coordinates. It sounds like you're missing a step somewhere.

Comment: http://s1.postimg.org/j8x7vj0jj/Untitled.png  The graphView is my hostingView. I think I'm using the layer wrong somewhere.

Comment: Try `graphViewLayer = graphView.hostedGraph`. The existing code creates a shallow copy of the graphView's internal layer, so it may not be laid out correctly when you use it to convert the coordinates. Since the graph is already a layer and is already laid out, it's easier and faster to use it directly.